# BTC/USD price on BTC-e

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate, btce

Can you explain me in detail, what affect the price on BTC-e ? I understand the mechanic, like if there is strong demand and limited supply the price goes up. But how does it work on BTC-e? Because to me it looks like the website is setting the price itself. There are lowest and highest ask prices.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly how a normal stock exchange works.

*The quoted rate and the **Buy** and **Ask** prices are just driven by the supply and demand of people wanting to trade on that exchange.*

BTC-e operates an order book. Sellers add **Sell** orders with an **Ask** price which they are happy to sell at (This is called a **Limit** order)
Buyers places Buy orders with a **buy** (or **bid**) price they are willing to pay.

The difference between the two prices is called a **spread**.

So if you place a **Limit Buy** order, but it is below the lowest **Sell** order then your order gets placed in the order book. If it was higher than the highest order, already in the order book, then the quoted **Bid** price will increase to the price you **Bid** at. Now if later someone else places a sell order at or below your bid price, then the order book will match your order and it will become a trade. (and vice versa).

When this happens. your orders are taken off the order book* and the next lower **Buy** order and next higher **Sell** order will become the new **Bid** and **Ask** prices.

Now if you want to make a **Buy** (or **Sell**) **Trade** right now: 
You can place a **Market** order which you say you want to **Buy** (or **Sell**) X number of coins (or shares on a stock market) i.e., you don't give a price.
When you do that, the BTC-e order book software will match the lowest sell limit order (or highest buy order when you are selling) and create a trade right away.

Which is the right order type to place, that depend on your trading strategy and is a whole other topic.

The rate quoted is normally the last price that a pair of orders that was matched at.

*It is slightly more complex than that, because you have partial fills, but you get the idea.

Comment: So the rate or price is the last trade?  It seems that sometime the price matches the lowest Ask and/or the highest bid.  Is this skewed because of partial fills?

Comment: Yes partial fills (or another Buy/Ask order at that price) or someone later adds an order at that last price (but there is still a spread to the other side of the trade)

Comment: FYI a fill is Your one order completes as several matching trades. As people wanting to buy sell exactly the same amount at a matching price is rather rare.